# How to order by column if equal, order by another

Tags: sql

Really I don't know how to say it as question, but with example it will be clear to everyone, I have data retrieved from MYSQL database sorted by one of columns , my question if one of those values in this column is equal, I need to use another column to set who is show first.

```
col1 - col2
10 - 100
20 - 120
20 - 140
30 - 90
```

see here value 20 mentioned twice so I need to show the 20 with 140 before the 20 with 120 using MYSQL Query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY 
    Col1,
    Col2 DESC
```

Comment: I've tried that but still show me wrong sort $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY platinum DESC, score";

Comment: ASC is the default sort order. Your desired results state you want col1 ascending, followed by col2 desc. if col1 = score, you want  "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY score, platinum DESC". if col1 = platinum, you want "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY platinum, score DESC"

Comment: Thanks for reply, yup I must order the two columns in desc order to get the desired output , appreciated you help.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify more than one column in the `order by` clause:

```
select * from table order by col1, col2;
```

This will order by `col1`, then order by `col2` when `col1` is equal.  You can also specify ascending and descending separately for each column:

```
select * from table order by col1 asc, col2 desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple columns in your `order by` clause.

```
select * from your_table
order by col1, col2 desc
```

The result will be ordered by the first column and if equal by the next and so forth